# What is a good way to add a programable offset to a diffential signal?

Tags: differential, differential-amplifier, dc-offset

I have an AC coupled, ~10 MHz to 1 GHz, differential signal, with a programmable gain, coming from a detector. The signal contain pulses, and the DC-balance is poor but constant (even if my hand drawings don't show it that well...). I would like to add a programmable offset to my signal to optimize its amplitude:

[image: Desired signal]

A Differential op-amp is already in the circuit to adjust common mode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVIks.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I add the offset without changing the common mode?

Comment: can you explain why you'd want to do that? It might hint to how you can achieve it, or what you could do instead. generally, your original signal looks "fine" to me, not any better than what you consider "optimized", so I'm curious.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm loosing nearly half of the range of the ADC with the first signal, because the differential signal is either slightly negative or largely positive.

Comment: So, you want to *amplify* your difference?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, I can already do that at a previous stage. I want to lower the maximum and the minimum of the difference, so the ADC resolution is better used with my signal. For example, I want an input with in+ between [-0.1, +2] and in- between [-2, +0.1] to be shifted to out+ [-1.05, +1.05], out- [-1.05, +1.05] when I apply it to the ADC.

Comment: Why do you want to shift each input signal? You can shift output (non differential) signal before ADC.

Comment: @Chupacabras Right now, the signal is differential from the sensor to the ADC. I'm trying to keep it that way because of grounding and shielding issues across two boards. I could use single ended signals in a section of the circuit. Can you draw me what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of how the signal is ground-referenced at all, but if you want OA1 to get a DC signal added to its inputs, current sources
of opposite signs applied to the terminals of R4 should
accomplish that.

Two sections of LM13700 (each is an operational transconductance amp)
can be programmed with matching (circa 1 mA) current sources and
connected to a +/- 1V trim input, one section having the trim
to its (+) input pin, the other to its (-) pin (ground the other
input pins).  The two outputs
are then complementary currents, and can be applied to the two
ends of the R4 resistor.   These are current source outputs; a choke
in series will prevent signal loading even at high frequency.

To get higher offsets, some resistor changes in the input
circuitry might be required.

Comment: The circuit reference is set by OA1 output common mode setting pin, that I omitted on the schematic.
This is an interesting approach. If I put the current sources across R5+R4+R6, at the input terminals of OA1, could that cause a problem? The required current would be smaller since the resistance would be higher.

Comment: @pserra Yes, across R+R4+R6 would work.  Another option: parallel a larger resistor across R4-plus-a-blocking-capacitor so the current has to go through Rlarger